# How to grab all members of a class instance with a given type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, c#-5.0

I have a class like

```
public class Stuff
    {
        public int A;
        public float B;
        public int C;
        public float D;
        public int E;

        public List<float> AllMyFloats { get {/* how to grab B, D,... into new List<float>? */} }
     }
```

How to grab all its contents of one type (say `float` in the given sample) and return them on property access?

Comment: What is your purpose of doing this? Why `List<T>` does not fit your requirements?

Comment: Legacy code, named access, in real life it is a list of other classes ofcourse

Comment: Then why would you keep the properties? Just replace it with a `List`, can't you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reflection is your friend.

```
public class Stuff
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public float B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public float D { get; set; }
    public int E { get; set; }

    public List<float> GetAllFloats()
    {
        var floatFields = GetType().GetProperties()
          .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(float));
        return floatFields.Select(p => (float)p.GetValue(this)).ToList();
    }
}

class Program
{   
    static void Main()
    {
        Stuff obj = new Stuff() { A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5 };
        obj.GetAllFloats().ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection for this.
Some pseudo-code:

```
public List<float> AllMyFloats
{ 
    get
    {
        var allMyFloats = new List<float>();

        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(float))
            {
                //Get the value for the property on the current instance
                allMyFloats.Add(property.GetValue(this, null));
            }
        }

        return allMyFloats;
    }
 }
```